# Find $\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^ks(n,k)$, where $s(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the first kind?

Tags: combinatorics

Find $\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^ks(n,k)$, where $s(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the first kind?

I was able to find that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kc(n,k)=\dfrac{(n-1+x)!}{(x-1)!}$ where $c(n,k)$ is the signless Stirling number of the first kind. Since $s(n,k)=(-1)^{n-k}c(n,k)$, I can multiply both sides by $(-1)^n$ and replace $x$ by $-x$ in both sides. Then I get $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^ks(n,k)=(-1)^n\dfrac{(n-1-x)!}{(-x-1)!}$. When $x=2$, we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^ks(n,k)=(-1)^n\dfrac{(n-3)!}{(-3)!}$. Is this result good enough? Should I get rid of the $(-3)!$? If so, do I have to use the Gamma function? Thanks!

Comment: Well, what is $(-3)!?$

Comment: I don't know. I had tried to do it with $x(x+1)...(x+n-1)$ instead of $\dfrac{(x+n-1)!}{(x-1)!}$, then replaced $x$ by $-x$. The result turned out to be 0 since $(-2)(-1)(0)(1)...(n-3)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the well known [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)

> $$ (x)_n = \sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k) x^k,  $$

where $ (x)_n = x(x-1)\dots(x-n+1) $. Now, you can easily prove that

> $$ (x)_n = \frac{x!}{(x-n)!}.$$

I think you can finish the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I could factor $-1$ out from each term on the right hand-side of my equation and I will get $(x)_n$.

Comment: @user116267: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with the exponential generating function of the Stirling numbers of the first kind, which says that
$$\left[n\atop k\right] = n! [z^n] [u^k] \exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
=  n! [z^n] [u^k] \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^u.$$
It follows that
$$2^k \left[n\atop k\right] = n! [z^n] [u^k] \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{2u}.$$
This yields
$$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \left[n\atop k\right] =
n! [z^n] [u^n] \frac{1}{1-u}  \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{2u}
\\= n! [u^n] \frac{1}{1-u} {n+2u-1\choose n}
= n! \left.  {n+2u-1\choose n}\right|_{u=1} 
= n! {n+1\choose n} = (n+1)!$$